# Add text in plot - Gini Index

Tags: r

I have a DF and would like to add text in `plot`.

My DF:

```
POPULATION = c(0,7009,14019,21028,28037,35047,42056,49065,56074,63084,70093)
INCOME = c(0,0,0,0,0,195680.26,550667.039999996,1034464.62,1821489.83,3360160.17999999,18979682.83)
DF=data.frame(POPULATION,INCOME)

library(ineq)

G = round(ineq(DF$INCOME,type="Gini"),3)

plot(Lc(DF$INCOME),col="darkred",lwd=2,main="Lorenz Curve", xlab="POPULATION", ylab="INCOME")
```

In my example the result of `G` (0.816) should appear in the lower right corner.
I tried with `text` but it didn't work out.

The result in the lower right should be "Gini = 0.816"

Comment: How about this: `mtext('Gini = 0.816', side = 1, line = 3, at = 0.99)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be the adjustment (`adj` parameter) in `text()` for justification of the text.

[image]

```
library(ineq)

POPULATION = c(0,7009,14019,21028,28037,35047,42056,49065,56074,63084,70093)
INCOME = c(0,0,0,0,0,195680.26,550667.039999996,1034464.62,1821489.83,3360160.17999999,18979682.83)
DF=data.frame(POPULATION,INCOME)

G = round(ineq(DF$INCOME,type="Gini"),3)

plot(Lc(DF$INCOME),col="darkred",lwd=2,main="Lorenz Curve", xlab="POPULATION", ylab="INCOME")
text(x=1.0,y=0
     ,labels=paste('Gini = ',G,sep='')
     ,adj = c(1.1,-0.1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a legend with Gini coeffcient, add this to you code :

```
 legend("bottomright", title="GINI",c("0.816"), fill="darkred", cex=0.8)
```